# Word for the thing on the picture

Tags: single-word-requests, professions

[image]
I cant find what that thing is called if at all there is a word for that. Does anyone know what it is?
This is some sort of load lifting device. Slings go in between the plates and well, there is a description:

> used together with rope or textile slings and serves for
>   simplification of unslinging process of represents a frame with the mobile
>   probe After installation of load on the place is done and sling is weakened of a sling, the probe is pulled out and load is released.

And here is another picture:
[image]

In Russian it is called literary "Smalles'(name of the inventor probably, but i couldn't find anythins on him) lock".

I found [this](http://www.freepatent.ru/images/patents/202/2267456/patent-2267456.pdf) patent. Similar device is called "device for remote unslinging". But maybe there is official name for that? [Here](http://russianpatents.com/patent/226/2267456.html) it is once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a **pin lock**, used as a sling-mechanism for handling loads using different types of slings (rope, chain, etc.) as bridles.

I didn't get a dictionary definition but found some sites from Russia thst you can relate to:

http://strop-nn.ru/gruzozahvatnye_ustrojstva/zamok-smalya-shtyrevoj-zamok

http://novaya-visota.ru/zakhvaty/zamok-smalya

http://www.gortorgsnab.ru/catalog/gruzopodemnoe-oborudovanie-mehanizmy/gruzopodemnye-zahvaty-mehanizmy/zamok-smalya

Comment: Well, there is no problem with Russian sites. I need English term for that thing. pin lock sounds like a credible term, but I still can't find any information if it is the exact same thing in English language.

Comment: It is difficult to find an equivalent english name because it is a different make of a lock or sling mechanism and not all of them have been named. I've seen several types of these in use in the ship building factory. Even the employees don't know its name.

Comment: Some kind of Shackle-Pin Locking-Mechanism for Rigging and Lifting http://marketplace.yet2.com/app/list/techpak?id=61482&sid=20&abc=0
Thank you for trying your best.

Comment: Yes, this one is pretty common. I've seen it. It is the **D-one**, as they called it.